# unable to fetch the facebook user profile after login with facebook in android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am integrating Facebook login integration. After login, I need to get the name, email, and profile pic of the user. I am getting the details but the profile pic is not showing up in my image view android.

```
 GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    currentAccessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.d("TAG", object.toString());
                            Log.d("res", object.toString());
                            Log.d("res_obj", response.toString());
                            try {
                                String id = object.getString("id");
                                try {
                                    URL profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?width=50&height=50");
                                    Log.i("profile_pic", profile_pic + "");
                                    String f_name = object.getString("first_name");
                                    String l_name = object.getString("last_name");
                                    String name = f_name + " " + l_name;
                                    String email = object.getString("email");
                                    String image = profile_pic.toString();
                                    Log.d("data", email + name + image);
                                    updateUI(name,email,image);
    
                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                   Log.e(TAG,"pic res"+e.getMessage()) ;
                                }
    
    
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
    
                                e.printStackTrace();
    
                            }
                        }
                    });
    
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "first_name,last_name,email,id,picture");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
```

// here I am getting all the details but the image not uploading and also I am getting exception like this.

> {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType:
> GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object
> with ID '502053987890832' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to
> missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read
> the Graph API documentation at
> [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%7D)

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation is quite explicit what problem is:

`Querying a User ID (UID) now requires an access token. Refer to the requirements table to determine which token type to include in UID-based requests.`

Which takes you to the [explanation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/#requirements). Reading this it seems you need to use user access token. The docs tell you how to get the access token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#android).

Regretfully Facebook API docs does not make it too explicit how to add the access token, assuming all its users are aware of OAuth 2.0 specifics. Still, you can simply add header `Authorization` with a value `Bearer <you-access-token>` to your request and this will authorize your access.